# How do I give template arguments to an object created inline with its class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

I know that in C++ we can do this:

```
class A {} a;
```

This makes an object of type `A` named `a`. It's equivalent to:

```
A a;
```

I was wondering how I would do this with templates. For example:

```
template <typename T> struct N {} <int> n;
```

This doesn't compile, but you get the idea. How would I specify the template arguments to an object created inline with its class definition? Is this even possible?

Comment: I don't there is a syntax that allows you todo that. Although you might be able to do template specialization and instantiation object original way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stuff after the closing `}` is called an `init-declarator-list` according to the standard.

14.3 explicitly forbids them to be used in template class declarations:

> In a template-declaration, explicit specialization, or explicit
>   instantiation the init-declarator-list in the dec- laration shall
>   contain at most one declarator. **When such a declaration is used to
>   declare a class template, no declarator is permitted.**

Comment: I just reported a bug to clang based on this answer, because it rejects `template<> struct A<int> { } lulz;`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that. The form you mentioned, for structures and classes is kept, from my understanding, for backward compatibility with c - where you could do that for structs.
Nice idea, though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare variables from a template definition, not even if all template arguments have defaults.

This also is an error:

```
template <typename T = int> struct N {} n;
```

- http://ideone.com/vFlIEg